# Can't post twice from the same AJAX TinyMCE textarea

Tags: jquery, ajax, tinymce

I've a list of elements editable via a simple AJAX/jQuery edit button, which works great. But when I try editing the same field a second time it doesn't want to play ball.

1. **EDIT** - AJAX returns a tinyMCE textarea containing content from MySQL
2. **SAVE** - AJAX posts tinyMCE contents to MySQL and displays posted content
3. **EDIT (again)** - Returns the same tinyMCE textarea and content as usual
4. **SAVE (again)** - The second time save is attempted, returns error: *g.win.document is null*

*Code snippets*

```
var content = tinyMCE.get('content').getContent(); //get tinyMCE content
$("#edititem").load("editItem.php", {content: content}); //jQuery post
```

---

*Solution* - this is how I got it working:

**EDIT** - when editing, add the tinyMCE control to the textarea

```
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl",true,'content');
```

**SAVE** - when saving, remove the control for next time

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',false,'content');
```

Comment: Hey Peter.  Is this solution still working for you?  I've tried it over and over and keep getting the same problem no matter what I do.  The editor works the first time and then is uneditable the second time and then just turns into a textarea box after that.

Comment: @grun8 I'd need to see some code you're working with but remember when this was an issue it took ages to figure it out and get it working. This solution should work in essence but depending on how things are working for you, there might be other factors to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am more familiar with FCKeditor but I think it is similar. TinyMCE has mceAddControl command to add/create editor instances. Are you doing that after you reload your content?

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl' ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, still do luck. The 2nd time the content loads it's now in a standard textarea not tinyMCE:

I also tried removing the control first:
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',false,"content");
    tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl",true,"content");

Comment: if its like FCKeditor, the browser receives a textarea and then some javascript plays with the DOM and inserts a contenteditable iframe (or div or somesuch). So in the cases where I have ajax-ed forms with editors, I need to re-run all the same code that happens during pageload on successful return

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I'd add a workaround solution that works in combination with the solution above:

```
setTimeout(function() {tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", true, "content");}, 5);
```

For whatever reason, I'm not sure if it's a timing issue with the DOM manipulation or something else, but a tiny delay makes life better.  However the `setTimeout()` did NOT work in combination with using a jQuery `.each()` method, such as:

```
$("textarea").each(function(index) {
    tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

That must be a whole different timing issue.

Anyhoo, thought I'd share these findings as I'm sure others and even possibly me again will find this posting helpful.

Comment: I was seeing the same issue and couldn't get any of the fixes to work until I introduced the timeout. Never would have thought of that.

Comment: I switched to the TinyMCE jQuery plugin and the issue resolved itself.  Not sure if this is an option for you or not but that was the best fix for my issue.

Comment: I had the same problem, chased it for a day.  Really strange, it would always work the first time the page was loaded, never on subsequent tries.  The timeout works perfectly.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(tinyMCE.editors).each(function(){
                            tinyMCE.remove(this);
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

For tinymce 3.2.x, use the following to remove tinyMCE instance in IE8 or any other browser. As tinymce.execCommand function makes input fields uneditable in IE8.

```
tinyMCE.remove(editor); //editor is instance of tinymce editor and not editor id
```

This will fix "Permission Denied" error without disabling other input fields in the same page.